Algorithms for experimental design and analysis of pairwise comparisons
I'm trying to create a model to predict an outcome ('Y') where there is minimal 'real' data on what contributes to Y. The high-level solution to this problem is to use a 'Knowledge Elicitation Process' (KEP) to attain judgements from experts on the contributors to Y, and then create a model from the expert judgements.
The specific solution I would like to implement is:

Identify variables that are likely to influence Y [likely to be
around 8 of these]
Determine realistic value bands for the variables
identified in 1. [Likely to be approximately 30 different bands
across all the variables]
Create a set of 'dummy' cases with different combinations of the variable value bands specified in 2.
Get the experts to perform a series of pairwise comparisons on pairs
of cases, specifying which is more likely to result in Y
Use the data from 4 to create a model using either: Method 1: Use data from 4 to rank-order the cases, and use this rank ordering to create 'weights of evidence' for each variable identified in 1 Or
Method 2: Use a Logit analysis to generate parameter values for the variables from the pairwise comparisons results

Steps 1 and 2 have been completed.
Step 3 and the arrangement of cases into pairwise comparisons for Step 4, can be specified via algorithms available in statistical packages.
The issues I have:

For the Logit analysis (5.2), the software package I am using is
suggesting I'd need at least 150 comparisons in the experimental
design, even with a 'reduced' number of variable value bands. Given
timescales/priorities, this is more than the number of comparisons
I'm likely to be able to get the experts to complete. I'd also prefer
to have more variable value bands if possible (which would increase
the size of the experimental design further).
If the ranking method is used (5.1) I believe there may be a way to
reduce the number of comparisons. For example if the experimental
design were organised so that redundant comparison were excluded
based on the results of previous comparison (e.g. if A > B and A < C,
little point comparing B and C as can infer C > B from prior
comparisons). However I am unable to locate either 1) an algorithm
that can provide a more efficient experimental design on this basis,
or 2) an analytical method of rank-ordering cases from pairwise
comparisons. The ranking algorithms I'm familiar with (e.g. ELO)
require large number of comparisons for each case, and so aren't
suitable.
Someone has also raised the possibility of getting the experts to
provide a scaled response to each pairwise comparison (i.e. rather
than just providing A > B, to specify the relatively extent to which
A >B using a simple Likert scale). Although this seems a good way of
getting more information from each comparison, I don't know how such
data would be incorporated into the model analysis (either ranking or
logit analysis).

So in summary could anyone provide any details/insight on:

How an efficient experimental design can be generated for pairwise
comparisons if the outcome is just to rank the cases
A method of generating the ranking from the pairwise comparison results.
Any insight into how scaled responses could be incorporated into the
above [or into a Logit analysis instead]

Appreciate this is quite a complex request. Happy for someone to point me in the direction of technical papers / software documentation rather than trying to fully explain in a forum post. I'm likely to have to implement any solution in either Python or SAS.
Thanks in advance.
